# Yii1 join 4 tables with condition

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have database for delivery of items to customers. for this i have 4 tables, delivery_logs, delivery,driver,customer

(we have delivery log table cause some time one delivery have many entries like not delivered & other driver take delivery etc)

```
delivery_log

id delivery_id driver_id  message     date_added
1  1           1         OK         2016-09-13 17:38:15 
2  2           2         OK         2016-09-13 17:35:18 
3  1           1         Not OK     2016-09-13 17:33:10     
4  1           3         OK         2016-09-13 17:32:13 
5  2           4         waiting    2016-09-13 17:20:11 


delivery
delivery_id  customer_id name          status
1            1           delivery 1    done
2            1           delivery 2    done
3            2           delivery 3    done


driver
driver_id  name
1          driver1
2          driver2
3          driver3

customer
customer_id  first_name   last_name
1            name1          other name1
2            name2          other name2
3            name3          other name3
4            name3          other name4
```

now i want to have query of

> last 1 record (order by date_added) from delivery_log
>
> for each delivery by each driver
>
> where delivery= done

and i want to have bellow fields

```
delivery_log.delivery_id  delivery_log.driver_id delivery_log.message date_added 
delivery.name driver.name 
customer.first_name customer.last_name
```

My `delivery_log` table have more than **991065**

how to build a YII Active Record query to execute this?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work on your "join" and "group" CDbCriteria attributes.

```
$criteria->join = ' INNER JOIN "delivery" del ON del.id = t.delivery_id';
$criteria->join .= ' INNER JOIN "driver" dri ON dri.id = t.driver_id';
$criteria->join .= ' INNER JOIN "customer" cus ON cus.id = del.customer_id';
```

You can then use the joined tables in "conditions" "sorts" and/or "group by"

```
$criteria->addCondition('del.status = \'done\'');
$criteria->order = 't.date_added';
```

And get the datas you need using a dataprovider.

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('delivery_log', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
```

This is not a full answer but it may help you go on and find what you need.